# Screen rotates on charger unplug

Tags: debian, wayland

I'm on Debian 12 (Wayland, standard Gnome desktop, kernel 6.1.0). When I unplug my laptop charger, screen switches from landscape to portrait mode, and keeps rotating 90 degrees at every unplug. I don't have any external display connected and it's an old MSI GE60 laptop with no rotation sensor. When I close and reopen the laptop lid, it switches back to landscape. I've taken a look at udev rules and saw nothing that could trigger this behavior. Any ideas what might cause this?

Comment: `keeps rotating 90 degrees at every unplug` ... are you saying that it rotates 90 degrees, then 180, then 270, etc. etc.?

Comment: @jsotola correct. Each unplug rotates the screen counter-clockwise by 90 degrees.

Comment: maybe it is a badly written script